# Why does reading from Stdout.Pipe repeats text?

Tags: go, stdout

I am trying to parse some errors from the stdout of a command. As command I use following example script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..4}
do
    echo "[the script] working... working..."
    sleep 0.5s
    echo "[error 1010] This is an error that occured just in this moment."
    sleep 0.5s
done
exit 41
```

My parsing code looks like this (imports shortened):

```golang
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("./test.sh")
    os.Exit(stdOutPipe(cmd))
}
func stdOutPipe(cmd *exec.Cmd) int {
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    cmd.Start()
    chunk := make([]byte, 20)
    for {
        _, err := stdout.Read(chunk)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        s := string(chunk)
        if strings.Contains(s, "error 1010") {
            fmt.Println("[your genius go tool] There occurred an ERROR and it's number ist 1010!")
            break
        }
        fmt.Print(s)
    }
    cmd.Wait()
    return cmd.ProcessState.ExitCode()
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
$ go run main.go
[the script] working... working...
rking[your genius go tool] There occurred an ERROR and it's number ist 1010!
exit status 41
```

The second line of the output repeats "rking" from the previoius line. How do I get rid of this? It would also be nice if you could explain why this repetition occures.

Comment: `_, err := stdout.Read(chunk)` dont forget `n` the number of byte written in `chunk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing away the return value of `read`. That gives you how many bytes were read.

```
 n, err := stdout.Read(chunk)
 s:=string(chunk[:n])
 if strings.Contains(s, "error 1010") {
    fmt.Println("[your genius go tool] There occurred an ERROR and it's number ist 1010!")
    break
 }
 fmt.Print(s) 
  if err != nil {
     break
 }
```

According to Read docs:

> If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. Could you explain in short why the number of bytes that are read varies? I mean, is this caused by sleep time between echoing those two lines in the shell script? Why does it not simply read as many bytes as possible if the text is not finished yet?